# How to show equivalence of the Hoare assignment axiom vs Floyd assignment axiom?

Tags: hoare-logic, software-verification

I know from several sources that they are equivalent, but couldn't find a reasonable explanation. My first approach was to show their equivalence by using the logical consequence rule and both axioms, but I couldn't figure out a reasonable solution.

Here is the exact problem definition:

[image]

Anybody can give me a hint how to show that both axioms are indeed equivalent?

Comment: As a first step, try applying each axiom to obtain the other, i.e. for given $F$, apply the Hoare axiom to $G:=\exists v'(F[v/v']\wedge v=e[v/v'])$, and for given $G$, apply the Floyd axiom to $F:=G[v/e]$. Can you show that the resulting pre-/postcondition are equivalent to $F$ and $G$, respectively?

Comment: We prefer that you not use images for critical content of your post (e.g., the problem definition). This makes your question harder to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).